# The usage of "on the way to"

Tags: grammar

Regarding the following sentence:

> I don't need to waste 2 hours on the way to and back from work anymore.

Is the phrase 'to and back from work' correct? I want to use it in an informal letter to a friend for Ielts writing task 1, so it needs to sound natural and totally correct. If not, could you please tell me the possible correct ways of saying that?

Thanks in advance,
Mojtaba

Comment: _to and from work_ is more idiomatic, so is _there and back_.

Comment: "To work and back" is common.

Comment: "Back and forth" is also common. I suspect there are regional difference.

Comment: 'To and fro' is the idiomatic; when 'from' is used, 'back' is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

**To and from** work

‘To and from work’ is the phrase that would normally be used, in English.

Example:

- I don't need to waste 2 hours on the way to and from  work anymore.
- The man made the journey to and from London every day.
- It takes 3 hours to get to and from Brighton.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from

You can also use ‘to and fro’ which describes the repeated movement of something going ‘back and forth’ - like a pendulum swinging.

- The man goes to and fro daily from London to Brighton.
- The pendulum swings to and fro.
- The waiters were going to and fro among the tables.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to-and-fro

Answer (score 0):

Traveling to and from work is known as **commuting**.

> travel some distance between one's home and place of work on a regular basis.

[Oxford](https://www.google.com/search?q=commuting%20defintion&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS829US829&oq=commuting%20defintion&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4742j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: But with no capital first letter.

Comment: Thank you for making that point.
I assumed Title Case was appropriate for a pithy reply but it does seem that  only archaic journals use the style for emphasis.

Comment: Why does this have 3 downvotes? *Commuting* seems very appropriate to me (or is there some other reason?). +1

Comment: Thanks for the defense, I was a little surprised by the downvotes but will be very much aware of correct form next time.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Justin - commuting is very appropriate and more widespread from my experience.

Comment: I wasn't one of the down-voters, but I don't think this answers the question in that the OP explicitly asked if the phrase "to and back from work" is correct and you didn't address that at all. Suggesting alternatives (and "commuting" is a good alternative) is useful, but the specific question should be addressed too.